# i have an OLE automation server (in fact, Open Office Calc) that doesn't close

Tags: delphi, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I have an OLE automation server (in fact, Open Office Calc) that doesn't close.  Is there a way I can see what OLE objects are not freed?  Truly, I think that because all the variables for this either go out of scope or are set to Unassigned, I shouldn't be having such a problem.  as a precaution, I even set the ones (that I found) that go out of scope to Unassigned.

I have been careful to close Open Office Calc in the way prescribed by an example for this.

This might be somehow related to the presence of (embedded) pictures I've been adding to the Office document.

How can I find the cause of this?

---

I think this is now solved.  I found that something about how pictures were being inserted was a "problem".  I don't have a complete understanding of why it was a problem but it's enough that it works.

Comment: can you please post the example code (or a link to it), so we can see what's happening?

Comment: Thank you @Johan for your reply.  there's so much code...i was hoping for some suggestions about any shortcut to finding the cause of this problem.

Comment: I am doing lot of OLE automation with OO and there never was such a problen. Maybe it would be good to write a small sample which does only some basic functionallity to test it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to display some example source in order to determine the problems you are having. However, you may also want to check out some example Delphi code found online to help accessing Open Office via Delphi: http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=8878

Comment: thank you for your reply & the link.  that was a nice piece of code (delphi to OO and Excel).  too bad i already wrote my own!  i'm thinking now i should test bench this problem to find the cause but i still hope someone can suggest a more general solution.